# OpenLayers shapefile polygons hover effect

Tags: openlayers-2, shapefile

I have shapefile polygons. I'm using OpenLayers with OpenStreetMap tiles.

Is it possible to create hover effect which will show up info window with some information about that polygon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SelectFeature popup.  Example can be easily changed to Hover instead of Select

http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.12/examples/select-feature-openpopup.html

different way to do popups

http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.12/examples/popupMatrix.html

Select with a hover (but no info box)

http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.12/examples/select-feature.html

...all the reference are there, you'll just need to put the pieces together.